# Python Gooey Run Directory

Tags: python

I'm using the latest [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey) library on Python 2.7 on Windows as a GUI for a simple `argparse`, but for some reason, the script keeps giving me the `[Errno2] No File Exists`.

I think it is because there is a space in the path of the Anaconda installation (i.e. `C:\Users\FirstName LastName\Etc.`) but I'm stumped.

I have tried `str.replace` all the `\` with `\\`, but I keep getting the same error message. Any ideas of what to do?

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import sys
import os
import json
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser

@Gooey(program_name="CPT Lookup")
def parse_args():
    stored_args = {}
    parser = GooeyParser(description='CPT Lookup')
    #Eventually make into checkboxes
    parser.add_argument('year',
                        action='store',
                        default=stored_args.get('year'),
                        widget='FileChooser',
                        help="CSV file with extracted year")    
    parser.add_argument('CPT',
                        action='store',
                        default=stored_args.get('CPT'),
                        widget='TextField',
                        help='CPT Code')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def loadCSV(year):
    #DO I DO SOMETHING LIKE YEAR.REPLACE('\','\\')?

    df = pd.read_csv(year)
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = parse_args()
    print("Opening CSV file")
    sales_df = loadCSV(conf.year)
```

Comment: So as far as I'm understanding this, the GUI works fine, but you're receiving an error when trying to open the file passed to `loadCSV()` stored in `conf.year`?

Answer (score 2):

This was an issue with the Gooey library itself (I'm the author). It wasn't quoting incoming file paths correctly.

If you pull down the latest release from PyPi (`pip install -U gooey`), your example script should run without issue.